# how to get automatic row number php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```
No   Name     Sex
1      A       M
2      B       F
3      C       F
4      D       M
```

I want to get automatic number on table with mysql database.
So how to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after - could you expand your question a bit more and help clarify what you're getting currently, and what you'd really like?

Comment: "automatic number on table with mysql database" what is that ??

Comment: Did you mean you want to get number in "no" field?

Comment: Are you asking about the Auto Increment value

Comment: Ex. row 1 2 3 4 5 6 on table auto number, with sql row number

Comment: Yes, I want to get number in "no" field auto number.

Comment: Question...why?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What does having the row number do for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do that,

One technique is to alter the table

- Alter table
- Add new column
- set it as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

And the other is to use session variable

```
SELECT @rank := @rank+1 As `No`,
       Name, 
       Sex
FROM   table1, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f60ce/3)

Answer (score 3):

You have create table with primary key and auto increment

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///example-auto-increment.html

See in below code:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
sex char(1),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: But, I delete the table, the next table is 1 3 7 9, I want the number is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 like that.

Comment: What is the mean of next table ?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic numbering is done by specifying the [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute for the numeric column you wish to automatically increment. It is good database practice to specify it on an 'id' column when creating a table, with each id uniquely identifying a row (also known as a primary key).

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  sex ENUM('m', 'f'),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Alternatively, you can [add the ID (auto increment) after the table exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a table that will do that automatically, roughly you can use...

```
create table mytable (
    `No` serial,
    /* other fields... */);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html

```
SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
```

However, if you delete rows you will have gaps in the row numbers.  If you want to reset the auto_increment field, use

```
alter table mytable
auto_increment = 1;
```